# node-archiver destination folder

Tags: node.js, zip, node-archiver

I'm using [node-archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-archiver) to zip some files and in the zip file I find the archived files under the directory where was zipped from.

So in the zip file, 'myfile.txt' is under this sort of directory:
'home/ubuntu/some_folder/another_folder/'
I want to have the files in the root directory of the zip file.

This is the code I suspect that is in charge with this:

```
archive.bulk(
   {src: filePaths}
);
```

Its documentation [is here](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/blob/master/BULK.md) although I don't see how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, not yet, I just had a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `expand:true`, `flatten:true` and indicate what name you want to use for destination folder (`dest: 'destinationfoldername/'`)

```
archive.bulk(
   {src: filePaths, dest:'destinationfoldername/', expand:true, flatten:true}
);
```

It workerd for me

Comment: the bulk() method is now deprecated.  Do you know how to flatten file names (remove directories from them) using the glob() or directory() methods?

Comment: Not sure about glob, but for directory just supply an empty string as [`destpath`](https://www.archiverjs.com/archiver#directory): `.directory(dirpath, '')`